# UPDATE SET with different value for each row

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, case

I have python dict with relationship between elements and their values. For example:

```
db_rows_values = {
     <element_uuid_1>: 12,
     <element_uuid_2>: "abc",
     <element_uuid_3>: [123, 124, 125],
}
```

And I need to update it in one query. I made it in python through the query generation loop with `CASE`:

```
 sql_query_elements_values_part = " ".join([f"WHEN '{element_row['element_id']}' "
                                            f"THEN '{ujson.dumps(element_row['value'])}'::JSONB "
                                            for element_row in db_row_values])

 query_part_elements_values_update = f"""
    elements_value_update AS (
        UPDATE m2m_entries_n_elements 
        SET value = 
        CASE element_id 
            {sql_query_elements_values_part}
            ELSE NULL 
        END 
        WHERE element_id = ANY(%(elements_ids)s::UUID[])
        AND entry_id = ANY(%(entries_ids)s::UUID[])

        RETURNING element_id, entry_id, value

    ),
```

But now I need to rewrite it in `plpgsql`. I can pass `db_rows_values` as array of `ROWTYPE` or as json but how can I make something like `WHEN THEN` part?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can pass dict as JSON, convert it to rows with `json_to_recordset` and change `WHEN THEN` to `SET value = (SELECT.. WHERE)`

```
WITH input_rows AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM json_to_recordset(
        '[
             {"element_id": 2, "value":"new_value_1"},
             {"element_id": 4, "value": "new_value_2"}
         ]'
    ) AS x("element_id" int, "value" text)
)

UPDATE table1
SET value = (SELECT value FROM input_rows WHERE input_rows.element_id = table1.element_id)
WHERE element_id IN (SELECT element_id FROM input_rows);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f8b6cd8285ec7757e0d8f38a1becb960